# Codebox, or another code library manager?

Tags: software-recommendation, development

Since I have Papers for all my documents, iTunes for my music/videos I'm only missing a good "code library manager/snippet manager" for all my pieces of code (especially for small projects or test code, as the bigger ones are easy to archives but little piece of code usually get more or less lost).

So I found [Code box](http://www.shpakovski.com/codebox/) but there's no trial version available. I looks like it has the features I want, so something like Paper but for code.

My question is: is it worth buying it ? Would you recommend another one I could test first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [Snippets](http://www.snippetsapp.com/)?  It's very comprehensive, easy to use and has a 30 day trial.

Comment: Great ! From Snippets blog it looks like the guy selling Code Box just "stole" the ideas from Snippets... (http://www.snippetsapp.com/blog/snippets-whats-happening.html). I'll test Snippets, at least for 30 days then.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider http://www.mcubedsw.com/software/codecollectorpro.

Comment: +1 for CodeCollector Martin (the author) is very professional. And he has submitted to the App Store a week ago I believe, check his twitter. I don't have experience with Snippets.

Comment: I'll have a look at that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Snipper App](https://snipper.app). It's a native MacOS snippets manager with modern, lightweight GUI, syntax highlighting, and Markdown support.

Comment: Please see the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and make sure you disclose if you are affiliated with a product.